# Choosing a controller and routes for a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, join

I'm building a favorites feature.

For instance:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites
end

class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
end
```

**Scenario**

I have a list of products, and I want to add a `[+] Add to favorites` link next to each product.

**My questions**

- Do I wrap the entire listing in a form tag so I can use POST to *some* controller -- or do I do something with a link_to_remote tag?
- Do I use the `create` action of the product controller, or should I use the favorites controller - or even the user controller (because it's the User's favorites)?

As you can see I am unsure of where to put code for a join table. Who "owns" what? I'm afraid of using bad anti patterns.

Answer (score 1):

you can setup the associations in your routes as well such as

```
resources :products do
  resources :favorites
end
```

this will allow you to handel the creation of favorites from your favorites controller

than you can wrap adding more favorites with link_to_remote linking it to your favorites#create